# How to compute the gradient and hessian of a vector valued function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

I'm trying to implement the algorithm below in matlab but i dont know how to compute the gradient and hessian of a vector valued function, i need to know how to do it to apply what is in the red underlined parts.
[image]

Lets say $h(x) =  ( (x_{1} +1)^2 + x_{2}^2 - 1, x_{1}^2 + x_{2}^2 -2, x_{1}^3) $ , how can I find the expression for the gradient and hessian of $h$?

Comment: Do you know what the gradient is ? Do you know what the Hessian is ?

Comment: @Digitallis yes, i just never did it for vector valued functions

Comment: The gradient for vector valued function is simply the Jacobian. And for the Hessian note that we consider $\nabla^2 h_j$ for each $j$, here $h_j:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, so it's the usual definition.

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\n{\nabla}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$Given the vectors
$$\eqalign{
h &= \m{h_i\\h_2\\h_3} \quad\qquad x = \m{x_1\\x_2} \\
}$$
the components of the gradient matrix $\LR{G=\LR{\n h}^T=\grad hx}$ are
$$\eqalign{
G_{ij} = \grad{h_i}{x_j} \\
}$$
while the component-wise Hessians $\LR{H_i= \n^2h_i}$ are
$$\eqalign{
H_{ijk} = \grad{^2h_i}{x_j\,\p x_k} \\\\
}$$

---

$\sf NB$: The reason for the transpose in the gradient definition is due to the way that the differential is calculated using Nabla notation versus Leibniz notation, i.e.
$$ dh \;=\; dx\cdot\n h  \;=\; \LR{\grad hx}\cdot dx $$